# Passing variable to a function consisting of multiple components

Tags: arguments

Consider the following example:

```lisp
(defun glue (str1 str2)
  (format "%s%s" str1 str2))

(setq str1 "Hello, ")
(setq str2 "World!")
(insert (glue str1 str2))
```

This inserts `Hello, World!` into a buffer.

I want to let the user define the format set in `(format "%s%s" str1 str2)`.

For example:

```lisp
(defun glue (str1 str2)
  (format "%s%s" hw))

(setq str1 "Hello, ")
(setq str2 "World!")
(insert (hw))
(setq hw (str2 str1))
```

This should return `World!Hello,`

However this returns `Symbol’s function definition is void: hw`

How can I set `hw` so it can be passed to `(format "%s%s" hw)`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: No, it doesn't return `Not enough arguments for format string`: the first error I get when evaluating the second block of code is on `(insert (hw))` which says: `(void-function hw)` which makes sense since there is no function named `hw`. That leads me to believe that you typed in something other than what you tested. Please check and edit the question so that it corresponds with what you tested.

Comment: @NickD you are right - checked on a fresh emacs - not sure how that happened. Edited to reflect correct error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your starting point is

```
(defun glue (arg)
  (format "%s%s" arg))
(setq str1 "Hello, ")
(setq str2 "World!")
(setq hw (list str2 str1))
(insert (glue hw))
```

You'll have to change `glue`. You need to pass two arguments to `format` after the format string, and `(format "%s%s" arg)` only passes one, no matter what `arg` is.

One possibility is to call `format` via the [`apply` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#index-apply). `apply` takes a list argument and calls the function with the arguments in the list (in addition to the ones that come before the list).

```
(defun glue (arg)
  (apply #'format "%s%s" arg))
(setq str1 "Hello, ")
(setq str2 "World!")
(setq hw (list str2 str1))
(insert (glue hw))
```

Another possibility is to make `glue` [take an arbitrary number of arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html#index-_0026rest) and pass the whole list forward to `format`. This again involves `apply`.

```
(defun glue (&rest args)
  (apply #'format "%s%s" args))
(setq str1 "Hello, ")
(setq str2 "World!")
(setq hw (list str2 str1))
(insert (apply #'glue hw))
```

Comment: Thank you - I think this is getting close however it returns the string `str2str1` not the value of those variables.

Comment: @TimotaySci Sorry, I had miscorrected. It's neither `(setq hw (str2 str1))` (that would apply the function `str2` to the value of the variable `str1`) nor `(setq hw '(str2 str1))` (that creates a 2-element list containing the symbols `str2` and `str1`) but `(setq hw (list str2 str1))` (create a 2-element list containing the values of the variables `str2` and `str1`).